# how to use NOT LIKE into query builder?

Tags: postgresql, symfony

I am using symfony 4.4 and postgres 11.7.

I have a class User with a json field "roles" (ex. ["ROLE_USER"], ["ROLE_USER","ROLE_ADMIN"]), and i'am trying to retrive users that roles field doesn't match with "ROLE_ADMIN" using QueryBuilder.

i've tried

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    return $qb
            ->where($qb->expr()->notLike('u.roles', ":roles"))
            ->setParameter('roles', $qb->expr()->literal('%ROLE_ADMIN%'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

but error is

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json !~~ unknown
    LINE 1: ...e_id AS sede_id_7 FROM utente u0_ WHERE u0_.roles NOT LIKE $...
    ^
    HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

so next step was use CAST (postgres) function

```
$query = $entityManager->createQuery("
    SELECT u
    FROM App\Entity\User u
    WHERE CAST(u.roles AS TEXT) NOT like '%ROLE_ADMIN%'
");
```

and error is

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 64: Error: Expected known function, got 'CAST'
```

the only successful attempt was to write query in standard SQL

```
$conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
$sql = "
       SELECT * 
       FROM utente u
       WHERE CAST(u.roles AS TEXT) NOT like '%ROLE_ADMIN%'
";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([]);
return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But i need an object's array, not two-dimensional array.

Some help?

Comment: I believe json fields are not properly supported by doctrine. you might be able to find the `CAST` function in doctrine extensions ... after a quick lookup, apparently only mysql's cast function is there, but maybe you can misuse that. have a look: https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions (and https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/config files)

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation I found this way of writing:

```
// Example - $qb->expr()->neq('u.id', '?1') => u.id <> ?1
    public function neq($x, $y); // Returns Expr\Comparison instance
```

Source: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class

Maybe it will help you